# Asp.net formatting lists of grouped data

Tags: asp.net, layout

I have a asp.net page where i query a list of url and the groups in the urls.  In the code behind i loop through each group and create a group header and then list all of the links.

something like this:

**Group 1**

Link 1

Link 2

Link 3

**Group 2**

Link 1

Link 2

Link 3

Now that i have a lot of links, this create one long list on the page and you have to scroll down.

What are the best suggestions for formatting this data using multiple columns or other layout options so it looks better on a single page rather than one long list.

Any example code would be great . . .

Comment: This is really a design / aesthetics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.NET 3.5 you could use [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) the control. A nice tutorial for grouping can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616112920/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx). If you are using ASP.NET 1.x or 2.0 you can try the [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) control (check the [RepeatColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) and [RepeatDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) properties). The ListView is more powerful.